# What does ぐぎぎmean?

Tags: words, definitions

I'm totally puzzled as to what this means, and I couldn't find any helpful hints when I searched through multiple websites. Does anyone else have a clue?

Comment: Welcome to JLU! Would you mind adding the reference to where you saw or heard this word?

Comment: Also, it may be helpful to look at the [FAQ] since this question may be considered too localized.

Comment: Can you provide some context?

Comment: This question has a deleted answer, which is visible only to moderators and users with 2,000 reputation points. Because I find nothing wrong with that answer, I wonder why it was deleted. It would be great if the person who posted that answer considers to undelete it or at least explains why it was deleted. (As a general rule, I would not like to disclose who posted a deleted answer when he/she does not reveals him/herself.)

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Oh ok, I've undeleted it now. I just figured that there was probably something wrong with it because of the downvote.

Comment: @cypher: Thanks for undeleting it.  There may be something wrong with your answer, but if there is, I fail to see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a variation of `ギギギ`, which originates from the manga `はだしのゲン` ([barefoot Gen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barefoot_Gen)).

It's onomatopoeia which refers to teeth grinding in anger, frustration or regret. It can also be used as a sort of "groan" symbolizing unbearable agony.

See also http://www.paradisearmy.com/doujin/pasok_gigigi.htm for more info.